# IIS URL Rewrite not working when trying to redirect sub domain to domain with query string

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting

I have what to me seems like a simple task with IIS URL Rewrite.

I need to redirect based on sub-domains to a main domain with a query string. For example

demo.domain.com needs to be redirected to [www.domain.com/?key=demo](http://www.domain.com/?key=demo)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="demo.domain.com" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="www.domain.com/?key=demo" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Found" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: I've gone through those docs countless times now and I am no closer to a solution. Any other more specific suggestions?

Comment: Fail request tracing is the best way to check the rewrite process, only in this way can you check the steps to find where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

What's happen when you digit demo.domain.com ?

Try to change your code like this :

```
<rules>
    <rule name="Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^demo\.example\.com$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/?key=demo" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Found" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

Look at the changes in line "add input=" and "action type="